# Enable all buttons that are disabled on wizard finish button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a few web user controls, which each uc_Control having 6 to 8 buttons in it. the controls are been using via a wizard control.
Each uc_Control is a matching game, so for instance if button_1 matches button_2 they are set to disabled and so on. So what i would like to do is when a user gets through all steps in the wizard and they click finish, to make all my buttons from all my uc_Controls to be enabled again.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

```
protected void BtnMatchimgButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //number 1
            int.TryParse(BtnMatchimgButton1.Text, out num);
            BtnMatchimgButton1.Enabled = false;
            Check();
        }

 protected void BtnMatchimgButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //number 1
            int.TryParse(BtnMatchimgButton3.Text, out num);
            BtnMatchimgButton3.Enabled = false;
            Check();
        }

  protected void Wizard2_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Wizard2.Visible = false;
            LblPageInfo.Visible = true;
            Wizard2.ActiveStepIndex = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In each of your uc_Control's have a method that toggles all buttons from enable to disabled and vice versa.

```
   public void ToggleButtons(bool enabled){
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {

                    if (c is Button)
                    {
                        ((Button)c).Enabled = enabled;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Quickly built code, and assumes the buttons are directly in the "root" control collection, you can do more checks to fit your needs, but this could get you started.